# Separate class declaration from it's implementation in PHP

Tags: php, declaration, class-design

I recently started to program in PHP. Should I separate class declaration from it's implementation like we usually do in C++ (header files)?

Comment: I don't think it is even possible in PHP

Comment: Nopes, You can't do that!

Comment: Don't see a reason why you should do this. Don't even think it's possible.

Comment: My bad, I just started to program in PHP and I thought that it is possible. Separating declaration from implementation seemed kind of natural for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not necessary in PHP. Nor is it possible. Remember that PHP is not a compiled language.

Comment: Oh well, my bad then. I'm sorry for asking such a stupid question. I presupposed that it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in PHP. PHP is not a compiled language.

See why you usually use header files in C++:

> Header files keep the function declaration separate from function
> definition. Your programs often need to use functions "defined"
> elsewhere... inside other .c/.cpp files or inside binary .obj files.
> Using the header files, you can "compile" your programs without
> needing the function definition.
>
> Now, for example you have a function foo:
>
> // the part below is the declaration -- should go to a .h file int
> foo( int, float );
>
> // the part below is the definition -- should go to a .c/.cpp file int
> foo( int a, float b ) { return something; }
>
> You can compile and link your function. From your .c/.cpp file, a .obj
> file is generated. You can now distribute your obj file along with the
> .h file. You now do not have to distribute the actual code.
>
> This is how you compile programs for windows... you don't have the
> source code for the windows functions. Instead you include windows.h
> file in your programs and the linker extracts the binary function
> definitions from the .obj files and merges them into your program's
> .exe file.
>
> https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080826000546AAsILy9

PHP doesn't have a compile phase and linker phase, hence no need to separate definition and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in PHP. You can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a class declaration, but you can and should write the class interface in a separate file.